# Pandas matching algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I have a dataframe like this one:

```
                     affinity
applicant_id job_id          
1            a              7
             b              7
             c              5
2            a              0
             b              4
             c              2
3            a              4
             b              8
             c              1
```

I need to match each applicant to a job so that (a) higher affinity is preferred; (b) no applicant is matched to more than one job; (c) no job is matched to more than one applicant. So in the example above I would like to get

```
                     affinity
applicant_id job_id          
3            b              8
1            a              7
2            c              2
```

The best I can think of is

```
tmp = candidates.sort_values(ascending=False).copy()
matches = []
while len(tmp):
    (applicant, job), affinity = next(tmp.iteritems())
    matches.append((applicant, job))
    tmp = tmp.loc[(tmp.index.get_level_values('applicant_id') != applicant)
                  & (tmp.index.get_level_values('job_id') != job)]
candidates.reindex(matches)
```

Can this be achieved in pandas without explicit iteration?

Comment: Do you have the same number of applicants as jobs?

Comment: @ALollz no, but I'm ok with unmatched applicants/jobs

Comment: Okay, Does every applicant have an affinity for every job? Or are there some applicants who cannot work certain jobs?

Comment: @ALollz only those pairs, which are in `candidates` are to be considered

Comment: Let mew asking a question why can not assign 2 to b and 3 to c ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben 1 fits b better (affinity=7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the typical [linear sum assignment problem](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html).

We'll make matrix, filling the missing values with some absurdly high penalty, so that they shouldn't ever get matched. A job will only appear in this matrix if at least one worker has an affinity for it, so this will work.

#### Sample Data

```
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'applicant_id': [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*3 + [4],
                   'job_id': ['a', 'b', 'c']*3 + ['h'],
                   'affinity': [7,7,5,0,4,2,4,8,1,10]})
```

#### Code

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='applicant_id', columns='job_id', values='affinity').fillna(-10**8)
#job_id                  a            b            c            h
#applicant_id                                                    
#1                     7.0          7.0          5.0 -100000000.0
#2                     0.0          4.0          2.0 -100000000.0
#3                     4.0          8.0          1.0 -100000000.0
#4            -100000000.0 -100000000.0 -100000000.0         10.0

opt = optimize.linear_sum_assignment(df1.to_numpy()*-1)
pd.DataFrame(df1.lookup(df1.index[opt[0]], df1.columns[opt[1]]), 
             columns=['affinity'],
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df1.index[opt[0]], df1.columns[opt[1]]]))
```

#### Output:

```
                     affinity
applicant_id job_id          
1            a            7.0
2            c            2.0
3            b            8.0
4            h           10.0
```

---

With more jobs than people we assign everyone, but some jobs remain unfilled. With more people than jobs, some low-affinity people remain unassigned.

Comment: Excellent! This is a different definition of optimal matching from mine but it still works for me

Comment: @BlindDriver how so? This should give you the maximum sum total of affinity for applicant-job combinations subject to the one applicant per job constraint.

Comment: Correct. My algorithm is different, however. I select a match with the highest affinity and then remove that applicant and that job from the list of match candidates Repeat until no match candidates are left.

Comment: See, I wrote (a) higher affinity is preferred; This is intentionally ambiguous because I am open to any reasonable cost function.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
job['applicant_id'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
job_a = job.sort_values(['applicant_id', 'affinity'] , ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['applicant_id'], keep="first").drop_duplicates(['job_id'], keep="first")
job_a = job_a.append(job[~(job['applicant_id'].isin(list(job_a['applicant_id']))) & ~(job['job_id'].isin(list(job_a['job_id'])))])
print(job_a)
```

Comment: that is multiple index not nan

Comment: I don't think this achieves what I want. Even in your 2nd line you get duplicates. Example: what if all jobs ranked the same candidate the highest? Then `job_a` will have that candidate selected multiple times